# Alter text in normal TextBox with Surface-On-Screen-Keyboard

Tags: textbox, keyboard, pixelsense

Is there a possibility to use the Surface-keyboard to alter text in a normal textbox?

I'm creating a textbox and add the text in code behind. And now I want that the user can change the text if he touches the text.

```
<Grid x:Name="TextContainer" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="Transparent" Height="66" Width="66">
        <TextBlock x:Name="contentTextBlock" Margin="0" Text="NodeDesign_X" VerticalAlignment="Center" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" />
</Grid>
```

I didn't find possibilities to alter the `SurfaceTextBox` in the way my `TextBlock` locks now.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `TextBox` instead of `TextBlock` then the user can change the text. If you are in Surface Mode the Keyboard will be automatic popup if the `TextBox` gets the focus.